# Import an Error class from a package in python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, tkinter

How can I import the Error class (and only the error class, not a namespace) in python to be used in an exception handling?

What's not intended to be used:

```python
from tkinter import _tkinter as tk

try:
    ...
except tk.TclError:
    print('Oops. Bad window path.')
```

I've tried the above, which works but doing so also imports a bunch of other things into my namespace that I don't need and I also need to use `tk.TclError` to reference it instead of simply TclError.

What I try to avoid, since it imports the whole package that I do not need, I solely need to handle the exception:

```python
import tkinter as tk

try:
    ...
except tk.TclError:
    print('Oops. Bad window path.')
```

So how do I import the Error class **alone** from the package, **without getting the whole tkinter namespace**, if that's even possible or recommandable?

I have two seperate Programs, I'll call them A and B here to shorten it.

What I would like to achieve

> A.py

```python
## Communicator ##
import B

#... Some irrelevant code ...
GUI = B.start()

try:
    #Tell the GUI to modify something, for example:
    GUI.entry.insert(0, 'Input')
except TclError:
    #Modification failed due to Bad Window Path
```

> B.py

```python
## GUI ##
import tkinter as tk

#Little Function to give the Communicator the required object to start/handle the GUI
def start():
    root = tk.Tk()
    run = Alarmviewer(root)
    return run

#... GUI initialization, creating/destroying of windows, modifications, etc
```

Comment: why are you trying to import `_tkinter`? That's not designed to be used by another other than the tkinter package. And why do you have to use it as `tk.TclError`? That doesn't make much sense. Can you explain what the bigger problem is that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Ok. Little clarification. The mentioned .py I'm getting the Error in doesn't have tkinter imported and this is wanted, since there is a seperate .py that handles the GUI elements. However, since I still need to somehow tell the GUI elements to modify sometimes it happens that I get a TclError when said GUI element doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't make much sense. I don't understand why you can't import tkinter in whatever code you have that needs to catch TclError. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You seem to be trying to separate your GUI and non-GUI code, and the non-GUI code needs to catch a GUI-related error. Is that correct? Why not have your non-GUI code import `TclError` from your GUI code? Make your own GUI code export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TclError` class can be imported from tkinter. To make it available as `tk.TclError` just import `tkinter` with the name `tk`:

```
import tkinter as tk
try:
    ...
except tk.TclError:
    ...
```

You can, of course, import just the `TclError` exception if you wish, though it really [doesn't have any actual advantage](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471/250313) over importing the entire module in this particular example:

```
from tkinter import TclError
try:
    ...
except TclError:
    ...
```

Your question claims you must reference it as `tk.TclError`, but that is a false statement. You reference it by the name you import it as. The name is irrelevant, what is important is the actual exception object itself.

For example, create a file named gui.py, and in that file put this:

```
# gui.py
import tkinter as tk
def do_something():
    raise tk.TclError("something bad happened")
```

Next, in another file add the following code:

```
from tkinter import TclError
import gui

try:
    gui.do_something()
except TclError:
    print("I caught the TclError")
```

When you run the code, you should see "I caught the TclError" printed.

Comment: Yea, does also work but not what I'm looking for. I clarified above.

Comment: @HackXIt: I've tried to add clarification. I think you have a slight misunderstanding of how importing and exceptions work.

Comment: Oh weird... I might have unnecessarily asked the question because at first try the from tkinter import TclError didn't work. Odd misunderstanding. The provided link regarding the fact that I actually do not benefit from this helped too, thanks! But for the sake of better reading I still prefer to use `from tkinter import TclError`, as it already suggests that I do not use anything else other than the `TclError` in `A.py`

Comment: Exporting the TclError from the GUI-code works good as well, might even be better because then I don't require to import anything GUI related in my non-GUI code. Great success!